# EndExecuteNonQuery Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i have an error as which is on the button click event, as its shows me an error message on this line:

com.EndExecuteNonQuery();

message text: Error 2 No overload for method 'EndExecuteNonQuery' takes 0 arguments

Thank you for your support

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["usradmadslistview"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string cmdStr = "Select count(*) from UserInfo where UID = '" + UsrNme.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());


        if (temp == 1)
        {
            chkusrnamlbl.Visible = true;
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}





protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["usradmadslistview"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string insertquery = "insert into UserInfo (UID,FN,LN,Password,Email,CountID,State,City) Values (@username,@firstn,@lastn,@passbox,@email1,@country,@state,@city)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertquery, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UsrNme.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstn", fnbox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastn", lnamebox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passbox", passtxtbx1.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email1", emailbox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DrDncoundrlst.SelectedItem.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", DropDownListSwestate.SelectedItem.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", citytxtbox.Text);

        com.EndExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");

        conn.Close();
    }

   catch(Exception ex) {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: shouldnt tou call ExecuteNonQuery....

Comment: [SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.endexecutenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Begin and End ExecuteNonQuery are used for asynchronous. I believe that was not what you intended because I dont see a Begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EndExecuteNonQuery` requires an `IAsyncResult` parameter as mentioned [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.endexecutenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, is this just a code snippet? Because I think you would want to use `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead. `EndExecuteNonQuery` is the end pair for asynchronously executing SQL statements.